is there a way to make iframe responsive in height with html content element in typo3?
I am using the content-element HTML in Typo3 to include iframes do display content that is generated from a database query (a php-file). This content was used in a former website that was created in the CMS called SPIP. last week, our company launched its new website in typo3, but I am looking for a way to properly display the iframes in height. in the former site, this was done by javascript, now with typo3 I am looking for a way to properly display the content in a responsive manner. but the height of the iframe is not fix, it is supposed to have a variable height, depending on the database output.
I tried several style attributes and codes from w3schools.com, but none did display the iframe as expected. typo3 is in general very responsive in displaying content, but it lacks this feature for the HTML content element.

Adjusting the height of an iframe to match the contained content is only possible via JavaScript. The iframe-resizer library can be used to make this simpler.
